# Why does !empty($variable) behave as an integer in this example?

Tags: php

I am reviewing some of my old code and found this gem. Not sure how I came up with it but it works.

This given code

```
echo time() - !empty($stored_unix);
echo "\n";
sleep(3);
echo time() - !empty($stored_unix);
echo "\n";
sleep(3);
echo time() - !empty($stored_unix);
echo "\n";
```

Outputs this:

```
1650155411
1650155414
1650155417
```

The documentation says empty() should return a boolean, but clearly here is not being treated as a boolean (nor a 0 or a 1). Does anyone have the answer to this?

EDIT:
I am editing this because my approach was wrong, and PHP does not treat `!empty($start_time)` as an integer > 1, it simply treats it as 1 or 0 which is the numerical representation of true and false.

```
$start_time = 5;
echo !empty($start_time);

echo "\n";
sleep(3);
echo "\n";
echo time() - !empty($start_time);
echo "\n";
echo time();
echo "\n";
sleep(3);
echo time() - !empty($start_time);
echo "\n";
echo time();
echo "\n";
sleep(3);
echo time() - !empty($start_time);
echo "\n";
echo time();
echo "\n";
```

Here you can appreciate that it's being treated as 1 and not 5, so I was wrong reproducing this.

Result of the above:

```
1

1650201075
1650201076
1650201078
1650201079
1650201081
1650201082
```

Comment: As default php treats everything as integer if possible. This is one of the biggest fundemantals of the language.  It has some advantages also might lead some problems in your code too. So better be careful.

Comment: How is it not being treated as 1?

Comment: @JamalThaBoss No, PHP does not treat everything as integer. You can do `"3" . "5"` and get `"35"`. It's matter of type conversion

Comment: @Justinas Unfortunately not my friend, if you create a string like "0e462097431906509019562988736854" it automatically converts it to an integer. That is why actually the MD5 collision exists on cyber securiy area of PHP.

Comment: @JamalThaBoss No, it will be string `string(32)` as long as you do not do something like `15 + "0e462097431906509019562988736854"`. You can't assign string that looks like int to strict typed property, it will throw error - means PHP _does not_ automatically converts random strings to ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to php [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

> An example of PHP's automatic type conversion is the multiplication operator '*'. If either operand is a float, then both operands are evaluated as floats, and the result will be a float. Otherwise, the operands will be interpreted as ints, and the result will also be an int. Note that this does not change the types of the operands themselves; the only change is in how the operands are evaluated and what the type of the expression itself is.

since time(): int returns int and !empty() returns true or false the restult will be an integer where true -> 1 and false -> 0

example: (php -a to access the php [interactive shell](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php).)

1. `true + 1 = 2;`
2. `false + 1 = 1;`